# Iterated of Picard-Lindelöf

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I had a problem sheet where I was asked to construct the 3 first iterated of Picard-Lindelöf of Cauchy Problems.

Now my problem is the term was not defined in class and I haven't found any definition online. The only information I have is a solution to the problem that was given. Here are a few examples, so if anyone knows what it is...

**Find the three first iterated of Picard Lindelöf of the following Cauchy problems**:

1. $y'=y^2+3x^2-1$; $y(1)=1

solution: $g_0(x) \equiv 1$, $g_1(x) = x^3$, $g_2(x) = x^7/7+x^3-x+6/7$

2. $f(x,y) = y+e^{y-1}$

solution: $g_0(x) \equiv 1$, $g_1(x) = 1+2x$, $g_2(x) = 1/2 + x + x^2  + 1/2e^{2x}$

If you want more examples, I can provide more

Answer (score 0):

(Please comment if my notation is unclear.)

The differential equation

$$\frac{d }{d x} y=y^2+3x^2-1 \wedge (x:=1)y = 1$$

is equivalent to the integral equation

$$y = 1+\int_{x:=1} y^2+3x^2-1$$

So define that the Picard Iterator of the ODE is:

$$Fx(y) := 1+\int_{x:=1} y^2+3x^2-1$$

Then the above integral equation can be written:

$$y=Fx(y)$$

That is, you're trying to find an expression $y$, dependent on $x$, that's a *fixed point* of the operator $Fx$. The actual fixed point can be hard to find, but we can approximate it by starting at the number $(x:=1)y,$ regarded as a constant function, and repeatedly applying $Fx$.

So lets do that:

$$y_0 = 1$$

$$y_1 = Fx(y_0) = 1+\int_{x:=1} 1^2+3x^2-1 = 1+\left[x^3\right]_{x:=1} = 1+x^3-1^3 = x^3$$

$$y_2 = Fx(y_1) = \cdots$$

Think you can take it from here?